# LINQ XML iterations

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How can i reach last node of XML through C#?
I am iterating through an XML document and checking a condition against a value and when the condition is satisfied, I want to reach last node in order to finish iteration. Can someone help please.

Comment: Sure thing, someone can help you provided that you will post your code.

Comment: So what have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: inside success block of my condition, i want to move cursor to lastnode of xml so that in the next iteration, it will come out of the loop.

Comment: Some code examples would be great. In general, getting out of loops can be done with "break;" statement. Getting last element within collection is done with ".Last()".

Can't give you more without some code examples.

Comment: show your code?Are you using `XDocument` or  `XmlReader` or `XmlWriter`

Comment: var Response = XDocument.Parse("XML");

Comment: @user3754877 why do you want to reach to the last node?

Comment: var Response = XDocument.Parse("XML");
foreach (XElement abc in Response.Root.Nodes())
{
if(abc.value == "required")
{
//TODO want to reach end of loop and exit(without using break)
}
}

Comment: Surely if you just don't break you will get to the end of the loop? If necessary an if statement can skip any work in the loop at that point... Or use a normal for loop and you can then set the loop index to the last value when your condition is satisfied.

Comment: Im sorry i want to reach end of XML (may be last node) not the end of loop. Sorry for type error.

Comment: What do you mean by reaching the end? Do you want to do something with the last node or something? Just having the code read to the end without doing anything is pointless and the code won't care if you stop reading half way through a document. In fact reaching the end of the document doesn't necessarily even make sense since you probably aren't actually reading it all in any traditional sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very good question, but if I understand you correctly, you want to finish the loop when some condition is satisfied?

this is done with [break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx);

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        if (i == 5)
        {
            break;
        }            
    }
```

In case you want to get the last element in collection using LINQ, this is done with ".Last()" statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a foreach loop and loop through each descendant. Check for a condition and if that is met, break out of the loop.

Get the last element beforehand and do something with that after you break out of the loop.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("myfile.xml");
if(xDoc == null || xDoc.Root == null)
    return;

XElement lastElement = xDoc.Root.Descendants().LastOrDefault();

foreach (XElement element in xDoc.Root.Descendants())
{
    if (condition)
    {
         // your logic
         break;
    }
}
```

---

It sure feels like I am doing your homework, but for the sake of this answer being valid (next time add this information in your initial question!), use the following:

```
XElement current = null;

List<XElement> elements = xDoc.Root.Descendants().ToList();
XElement lastElement = elements.LastOrDefault();

for (int i = 0; i < xDoc.Root.Descendants().Count(); i++)
{
    current = elements[i];
    if (condition)
    {
        // Set i to the highest available number which causes the loop stop.
        i = xDoc.Root.Descendants().Count();
    }
}
```

Comment: cant use break. Need an alternative

Comment: Maybe you should have stated that in your question. Why can't you use break?

Comment: What is the situation that means you can't use break? Is this a homework/interview question with arbitrarily imposed rules or is there something about your program structure which for some reason imposes this restriction?

Comment: There, a solution without break. You could make performance slightly better if you only use the `Count()` once and store it in a variable before getting into the loop.

Comment: Our Code review team is against using of break.

Comment: I would love to have the "why not to use `break` -presentation" from them.